# Cant create correct regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have an html text. With my regex:

```
r'(http[\S]?://[\S]+/favicon\.ico[\S^,]+)"'
```

and with `re.findall()`, I get this result from it:

```
['https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196', 'https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico,https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico?v=ec617d715196']
```

But i dont want this second result in list, i understand that it has coma inside, but i have no idea how to exclude coma from my regex. I use `re.findall()` in order to find necessery link in any place in html text because i dont know where it could be.

Comment: Character class negation can only be applied to the whole charset and must be specified at the beginning of the charset `[^abc]` <- "not a, b, nor c". `[^\s,]+` would likely fix your issue but it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: The same result, it doesnt work, bro. For the point, i am from Ukraine too)

Comment: Solved!!!!!!!!! You gave me an idia and it is work `r'(http[\S]?://[^,\s]+/favicon\.ico[^,\s]+)"'` @MonkeyZeus

Comment: You are writing `\S` but that might not mean what you think it means. `\S` matches any character that is NOT a **space**. You seemed to have used it to mean a singular `s` like in `https`.

Comment: Do you need `https?://[^\s",]*/favicon\.ico[^",]+`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `[\S]+` contains redundant character class, it is the same as `\S+`. In `http[\S]?://`, `[\S]?` is most likely a human error, as `[\S]?` matches any optional non-whitespace char. I doubt you implied to match `http§://` protocol. Just use `s` to match `s`, or `S` to match `S`.

You can use

```
https?://[^\s",]*/favicon\.ico[^",]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JHtgBO/1).

*Details*:

- `https?://` -  `http://` or `https://`
- `[^\s",]*` - zero or more chars other than whitespace, `"` and `,` chars
- `/favicon\.ico` - a fixed `/favicon.ico` string
- `[^",]+` - one or more chars other than a `"` and `,` chars.